# Why don't :before and :after pseudo elements work with `img` elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

I am trying to use a [`:before` pseudo element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) with an `img` element.

Consider this HTML and CSS...

#### HTML

```
<img src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/this-is-not-a-hash" alt="" />
```

#### CSS

```
img:before {
  content: "hello";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPt7m/).

This does not produce the desired effect (tested in Chrome 13 and Firefox 6). However, it works with a `div` or `span` element.

Why not?

Is there a way to make pseudo elements work with `img` elements?

Comment: I wrote this (not fantastic) answer that's relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements

Answer (score 171, accepted):

[The spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)...

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of `::before` and `::after` with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

I guess this means they don't work with `img` elements (for now).

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements/6949190#6949190).

Comment: *This will be defined in more detail in a future specification*. **Ahem** "PUNT!"

Comment: The real SOer should ask a question and 3 minutes after answer to himself, +1 ;-)

Comment: It's the future, still no specs...

Comment: It's the future again, still no specs?

Comment: @kangax Maybe we should write it and submit it the W3C.

Comment: The abandoned [CSS3 Generated Content module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#replacedContent), which was last updated 10 years ago, says "Replaced elements do not have '::before' and '::after' pseudo-elements; the 'content' property in the case of replaced content replaces the entire contents of the element's box." So presumably this has been accounted for already, except this module was never implemented and is currently still pending a rewrite.

Comment: Again! Future! What's going on?

Comment: Sure would be useful right about now

Comment: 4 years into the future and still waiting!

Comment: THIS iS 2016...this is why mobile native apps will win.

Comment: Its 2016 And still waiting!!!

Comment: 2017 here, same.

Comment: mid 2017 here, still no specs...

Comment: Almost 2018, still no specs.

Comment: 2018.. still counting

Comment: *Le sigh* Still waiting in 2018... BibleThump

Comment: Still the future.......

Comment: It's 2019, and 8 years passed. When will we reach the future exactly?

Comment: Does the future exist?

Comment: Future does not exist yet

Comment: Still waiting for the future to exist. Did we all die already?

Comment: Have someone reached future? 2019. Stil no spec.

Comment: Still waiting; while working from home. Because COVID-19.

Comment: Nearly 10 years later, many of us have gray hair and some have passed away. We have self-driving cars, but pseudo-elements on images is the one bit of technology that we can't figure out.

Comment: A suitable solution is to add a container class around the image and add the :before or :after to that to get the same or similar effect.

Comment: That's shame it's still not possible in 2020. I laughed a lot at [Kellen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements#comment109669977_7396482) though. Self-driving cars are easier than pseudo on an image... But soon Tesla will find out that they have a browser in their car, and it doesn't support pseudos on img, and Musk will have a heart attack, and universe will finally collapse. I hope then they will invent pseudos on images. RIP Musk

Comment: 2021. We keep waiting with undeads. (Last year corona came)

Comment: It's now or never.

Comment: 10 full years have passed. We now have foldable screen phones, OLED portable consoles and gun-toting robodogs. The img::after pseudo-element has become a front-end fool's errand.

Comment: You can add it before/after the parent element of the image and then use z-index to place it before/after the image.

Comment: 2023, it's been over a decade and I ended up here

Comment: 2024 has dawned, WW3 might have begun in the Middle-East, and there's still no flippin' pseudo-elements on my flippin' images!

Answer (score 13):

It could be that browser vendors have not implemented pseudo elements on the `img` tag because of their interpretation of the spec: the `img` element, strictly speaking, is not a block level element or an inline element, it is an [empty element](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html).

Comment: This seems correct, though the terminology has shifted since that HTML3 link (!). In HTML5, an img is what's called a "void" element. Examples of void elements include hr, input, and source. See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element // A quick bit of informal testing suggests that you can't add pseudo-elements to input elements either.

Answer (score 8):

Just for testing and knowing it's not pretty you can do the following to make the pseudo elements work with 'img' elements.

Add: `display: block; content: ""; height: (height of image)px`
to the img element in your CSS.

Though it will render your img tag empty cause of the `content: ""` you can then

Add: `style="background-image: url(image.jpg)"` 
to your img element in html.

Tested this in Fx, Chrome and Safari

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Mac Firefox 17.

Comment: Only works for me in Firefox 23 if the image tag has a src that doesn't exist (404).

Comment: I solved this by wrapping the img to span. Hackish, yes, but works in some occasions.