# Using :pseudo selector on img tag on hover

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to get the same pseudo element on a `div` and an `img` tag.

While the `div` works just fine the element doesn't show up on the `img` tag. I use this CSS (simplified):

```
div:hover:before, img:hover:before{
    content: 'pseudo';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Please check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revaxarts/7PSN2/1/) for the example

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements

Comment: Thanks guys, please vote for closing this question!

Comment: You could just delete it