# Unable to add an Image over another Image using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Well I was trying to display a small logo image over another image (by default on all images) by using CSS but somehow nothing is displaying. Here is the CSS I used

```
img:after
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
z-index: 1px;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51558405/small.png) no-repeat;
}
```

The image on which I try to do this are standard 640x360 size. I thought using z index component for the background image might get it in front but no use. Since I wish to do this with all the images by default, I can't afford to use editing html manually so is there a way of doing this without having to edit html and just CSS or scripts?

Comment: Post a *complete* code example please.

Comment: this is the only image css code for the img

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question properly. You want an image and over it, a logo that is also a link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Psudeo Elements with img tags as evu points out, but you can wrap your image tags in an element and apply the psudeo element to the wrapped element. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7NNs/2/)

```
<a href="#" class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250X250"/></a>

a.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

a.image:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 1px;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51558405/small.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: haha after evu's answer I was doing something like this as well! :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Psudeo elements do not work on img tags.

See this question/answer: [Why don't :before and :after pseudo elements work with `img` elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements)

Comment: oh I see that was the problem ! So id there a way of doing it without pseudo elements in css

Comment: It depends on your existing content and styles. What is the image contained within? (html & css)

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4Z7H3/ may be of use, but again it depends on the img parent and if that has position relative or so.

Comment: It's simple img tag inside <a> link tags

Comment: In that case, you can `display: none;` the image and make your new image a background image for the `<a>` tag. Or use JS to replace the image source, or remove the image and replace it with a new one... Really, it's a matter of context and content.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Z7H3/2/

Trick is to use position relative and absolute in order to create the effect: using a wrapper with position relative, you can absolute position elements over that element.

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="bg-image" src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    <a href="http://what.ever"><img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper { overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.logo { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: 1px solid red; }
```