# How to put image on image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can't make it work. I need to put some images on page and then put some default image on every image that I've put before.
Here I put some images on page:

```
tmp = 0;
for(var a = 1; a <= get_height; a++){
    for(var b = 1; b <= get_width; b++){
        document.write("<img src=" + shuffled_mass[tmp] + "class='image'>");
tmp++;
    }
    document.write('\n');
}
```

It works fine. But I can't put default image on top of those.
Tried to do it with css:

```
.image {
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}
.image:after {
    z-index: 3;
    background-image: url('/static/test_app/image/default.png');
    height:96px;
    width:96px;
    display:block;
    content: ' ';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

But that didn't work.
Could someone, please, help me with this?

Comment: please clean the code above and also post html

Comment: @messerbill edited post. html is empty. It is filling with js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `:after` on image. 
See this question: [Why don't :before and :after pseudo elements work with `img` elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements#7396482)

You have to wrap the image with element (let's say `div`) and use `:before` on it.

```
.image {
    display:block;
}

.wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
    z-index: 3;
    background-image: url('/static/test_app/image/default.png');
    height:96px;
    width:96px;
    display:block;
    content: ' ';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Edited the question. I put images on page with js document.write("<img src=" + shuffled_mass[tmp] + "class='image'>"); and there I give all images class="image". Can understand how to make it work with your advice.

Comment: Just replace `document.write("<img src=" + shuffled_mass[tmp] + "class='image'>");` to `document.write("<div class='wrapper'><img src=" + shuffled_mass[tmp] + "class='image'></div>");` (You can remove the `.image` class attribute, you don't need it.

Comment: That didn't work. Just place all images not in line, as it was befor, but in colomn

Comment: Can you post a image with the result? I can't understand what do you mean.