# how can I add ::after or ::before to a image tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, selector

I was doing a project and I wanted to add **::after** tag (I used ::before too) for one of my images (I used **img** tag)but it doesn't work I don't know what should I do thank you for helping me

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is impossible to use pseudoelements with img tag.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements) you can see the similar discussion