# CSS3 "Tooltip" with :hover:after positioning and size

Tags: css, tooltip

I know it is possible to create a custom "tooltip" with the `:hover:after` selectors and to align this tooltip relative to the original element by marking the original element as `position:relative` and the tooltip as `absolute`.

**HTML:**

```html
test
<span custom-tooltip="testing a custom tooltip" class="tooltip">
    test
</span>
test
```

**CSS:**

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
    content: attr(custom-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

However, I must use absolute values to position or size this `:after` element

```css
top: 30px;
left: -30px;
width: 300px;
```

What if I want to make the element as wide as it needs to be (Percentages are relative to the parent element creating a large vertical box so I can't tell it to go `width: 100%`)

And centered under the parent (`left: -50%` results in it being moved 50% of the parent to the left, not centered)

Is this possible without javascript? (If not, are there some magic selectors or functions to get the width of this or that and `calc()` the correct values?

Comment: You can make it as wide as it needs to be by only declaring a left or right value, without any width. I have tried to get it centered using only CSS before to no avail. Hopefully someone else has a solution!

Comment: In my tests it still holds the width of the parent object if you don't give it a specific width (Or in the case of `left:` it continues until the right boundry of the parent object)

Comment: Here is a pure CSS tooltip I did a while ago, the width is flexible. http://joshuanhibbert.com/sandbox/css-tooltips

Comment: Very nice, shame it scrolls off the screen if so positioned though.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by scroll off the screen?

Comment: If you were to randomly position a link near the right side of the browser the tooltip would still scroll off-screen

Comment: Ah, yes, unfortunately. I believe that like the centering, some sort of JavaScript will need to be used to avoid that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can force the tooltip onto a single line by using `white-space:nowrap`. I don't know of any way to center the tooltip without forcing a specific width on both the tooltip and the item the tooltip applies to. Here's a general-purpose example (without centering):

```
<p>Lorem <span tooltip="Lorem ipsum">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet.</p>
```

And the CSS:

```
*[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #000;
}
*[tooltip]:hover:before {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Note that I'm using `:before` instead of `:after`. If you want to center the tooltip and are able to define a fixed width, you can use this CSS instead:

```
*[tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 -75px;
}
*[tooltip]:hover:before {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Here, the item is given a fixed width equal to the width of the tooltip then negative left/right margins to collapse it back down to the desired size. Note the addition of `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center`.

This technique isn't practical for inline tooltips, but works well for buttons and "call to action" links.

Comment: The `nowrap` trick is great, but it allows the tooltip to scroll off screen (And create a nasty scrollbar and potentially screw up a layout) how would you prevent that?

Comment: You can prevent the scroll with `overflow-x:hidden` on the body, but the tooltip would just be cut off. CSS doesn't have any support for position-aware styles, so the only way to change the behavior near the edge of the window would be with JavaScript.

Comment: All right, I suppose that works. So the only way to really make such a tooltip work is with javascript?

Comment: Yes. And there are plenty of tooltip plug-ins available for jQuery or any other JavaScript library.

Comment: Great solution! One note: **::after** does not work with img or input elements, so a wrapper must be added for this kind of replaced elements, and the tooltip assigned to the wrapper. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements)

Answer (score 0):

```
.tooltip
 {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
 }
.tooltip:hover:after
 {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(title);
  left: 20%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 220px;
 }
```

code from [TalkersCode](http://talkerscode.com) complete code here [Create CSS3 Tooltip](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-simple-tooltip-using-css3.php)