# HTML5 Tooltip via css and data- field works on link but not on image

Tags: css, html, custom-data-attribute

following the tutorial http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ I wanted to adapt the process of creating a tooltip for images (not links). So I adjusted the "tooltip" class rules to be generic and not `a` tag specific.

I reproduced my efforts in the js-fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AqPN8/

As you can see in the fiddle  it does work for links but not for images. Do you have any idea why not?

Technically I think that `:hover` and alikes should also for for `<img>` and not only `<a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images do not allow for pseudo elements, thus setting a `:before` or `:after` on an `<img>` will not work.

Read for more info:
[CSS :after not adding content to certain elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements/6949190#6949190)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `::before/::after` pseudo-elements on tags that cannot have children, i.e., `<img>`, `<br>`, `<hr>`, etc: [MDN Documentation for `:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore)

> `:before` creates a pseudo-element that is the first **child** of the element matched.

Answer (score 3):

> [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched.

`<img>` element is an *empty* tag not a *container* tag, you can't use `::before` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) on elements like `<img>`.

As an alternative, you can wrap the image by an inline wrapper element like `<span>`:

```
<span class="tooltip" data-tip="show a tooltip for image">
    <img alt="show a tooltip for image" src="path/to/image" />
</span>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/AqPN8/1/)**.