# :after css not working for img tag. is there any replacement for this?

Tags: html, css

`:after` css not working for `img tag`. Is there any replacement for this? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GhVbR/)

```
img {
    border-radius:50px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

img:after {
    content:"hi";
    width:20px;
    height:3px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:47px;
    background:#000;
}

<img src="http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/files/2012/12/Beautifull-cat-cats-14749885-1600-1200.jpg" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS :after not adding content to certain elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements and many more...

Answer (score 2):

Only solution is to wrap the image inside a span:

```
<span><img src="http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/files/2012/12/Beautifull-cat-cats-14749885-1600-1200.jpg" /></span>
```

And use this CSS:

```
span {
    position:relative;
}
img{
    border-radius:50px;
    height:100px;
}
span:after{
    content:"hi";
    width:20px;
    height:3px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:47px;
    background:#000;
}
```

Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GhVbR/1/)

Comment: Since an image is an inline element, I've chosen to wrap it inside another inline element. But yes, it is also possible to wrap it inside a div or a paragraph. But do note that those elements are block elements and might need more adjusting then needed to fit in the design.

Comment: inside a span, a div or another container element (html5 has a couple of others to choose from). Also, this answer lacks a bit of explanation about *why* it doesn't work, but fortunately that is covered in the question of which this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap it in another element, it works: **http://jsfiddle.net/GhVbR/4/**

html

```
<div class="kittenframe">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100" />
</div>
```

css

```
.kittenframe img{
    border-radius:50px;
    height:100px;
}

.kittenframe {    
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.kittenframe:after{
    content:"hi";
    width:20px;
    height:3px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:47px;
    background:#000;
}
```