# Overlay gradient over image with CSS

Tags: css, image, joomla, overlay

I'm getting frustrated with this thing. I'm using Joomla and Phoca Gallery which generates this part of the code:

```
<img class="pg-image" src="/images/phocagallery/other/thumbs/phoca_thumb_m_something.jpg" alt="Something">
```

What I want to do is to overlay gradient over the image that is shown as thumbnail on the website (the image with .pg-image class). As the image is not background image, all solutions for overlaying gradients I found on the internet so far are not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, everything that I found points to use the ":before" selector and then applying background with gradient.

Comment: Somehow the StackExhange didn't show the code properly, check the corrected code above.

Answer (score 6):

[CSS :after not adding content to certain elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements/6949190#6949190)

This cannot be done only by img tag you need to add extra markup to it like enclosing it in a div.

```
<!-- http://www.jmonit.com -->
<div class="pg-image">
<img src="http://www.jmonit.com/kettlezoozebraGZ1/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/memcarrd_HD.jpg" alt="Something">
</div>
```

See an example here

http://codepen.io/jmonit/pen/gbGayg

Answer (score 4):

Create an overlay div:

```
<div class="image">
  <img class="pg-image" src="http://i.guim.co.uk/static/w-620/h--/q-95/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2015/1/30/1422631112598/2340075f-69ad-443b-9770-2dd03049f474-bestSizeAvailable.jpeg" alt="Something">
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>

.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(55, 155, 55, 0.5);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image{position: relative;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fhxwcyp/)

Comment: That would be perfect solution, but Joomla generates code, not me, so I can't really create new div. At least I don't know how.

Comment: You can add markup in the gallery plugin templates, but a better solution would be to look for another plugin which does what you want or build the viewer yourself. I can recommend the Caroufredsel script which has a lot of great image galleries which can also be customized to your liking. [link]http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/