# How to style SVG node with :before pseudo element

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, pseudo-element

I'm trying to style react-d3-map's marker image.
There is no way to change its image (except for the change of library's code), so i'm trying to hide it and use :before pseudo element.

```
 <image class="icon-map-marker marker"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,[...]==" <!-- hardcoded in library -->
        x="141.98888888888882" y="163.8247013673872"
        height="25" width="25"
 </image>
```

but all the css definitions in chrome's developer's console are grayed out and of course not working - similar in FF

```
[class*="icon-"]:before {
  content: "0";
  min-width: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.icon-map-marker:before {
    content: "\107F";
}
```

This CSS works great for HTML element.
Is it all possible to create pseudo element for SVG node?
Maybe some other way to change this image?

Update: I don't want to set :before on SVG element. But on image node inside SVG hierarchy.

Comment: @Mr_Green, I think it's the opposite here, OP wants to set `before` pseudo element **on** a SVGElement. and it's not possible though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudoelements can't be applied on `<image>` Tags. the specs are saying this:

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements/6949190#6949190)

Comment: `<image>` is not IMG, But any svg element is considered a replaced element.

Comment: Never said that <image> = <img>. the note sais "such as IMG" ...

Comment: But nothing in your quote says that it applies to `<image>` nor svg elements in general.