# Adding linear gradient to an image using :after pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I am working on a category section where the image has[image] has a category on the top right, titles on the bottom left and a linear gradient at the bottom i.e., the background of the titles. Using a pseudo class :after I want to insert the linear gradient to the background. As you can see the image is in the HTML tag not in the background but it won't work even when I give z-index. What am I doing wrong?

Any Suggestions and help are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category-list li {
  flex: 0 1 31%;
  position: relative;
}

.category-details img:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  z-index: 999;
}

.category {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: #00ae6f;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.category-details {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.overlay-title h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list">
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://preview.ibb.co/eEi2Cb/CBSE_Building_design_plans.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try `:after` on some element other than `img`.

Comment: I know that I could take that image in a div and give the linear gradient to that div but why can't I give it to the image.

Comment: You need to add `content: ''` and fix a typo in `linear-gradient()` method. You are using `rgb` which does't accept alpha channel. It must be `rgba` to work correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately `:after` and `:before` on `img` doesn't work on most browser referring to these answers: [Solution-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements) and [Solution-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements). hope this helps.

Comment: @mohammed Usman It worked with your suggestions. Can you answer the thing you just said so that I could accept it.

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan There are already two answers with the similar solutions. Its not good idea to post the same idea again. You can accept any one of them. That's is perfectly fine as far as your problem is solved :)

Comment: @mohammed Usman But you were the first to tell me and it worked when I've tried, So legally your answer should be accepted. Anyways It worked Shukran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems

1. Use `::after` instead of `:after`.
2. An `img` can't have a pseudo element. Sorry.
3. A pseudo element should have `content: "";` property otherwise it wouldn't appear at all.

Use `::after` on the `category-details` and make sure that any other element insidw `.category-details` has a greater z-index (the text, i.e the title etc) otherwise it will be behind the `::after` element.

Answer (score 2):

First thing; CSS pseudo-elements are not going to work on the `img` element. Why? Read some about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396469/why-dont-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-work-with-img-elements).

Secondly; you've also been making a little mistake in the `linear-gradient` CSS function. In the code above, you are/were using `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4)` instead of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)`, I think I don't need to talk more about this as unlike `rgba()` the `rgb` function doesn't allow you to use an *alpha* value.

Here is my quick take on what you are trying to achieve.

```css
/* Used the box-sizing reset to avoid sizing issues */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Killed that annoying additional margin below the images */

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.category-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category-list li {
  flex: 0 1 31%;
}


/* Relatively-positioned the `.overlay-title` container */

.category-list li,
.category-details {
  position: relative;
}

.category {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: #00ae6f;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.category-details {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Made the appropriate positioning, display, and background changes to the overlay div. This will do the job. */

.overlay-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 999;
}

.overlay-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.overlay-title h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* Gave some margin to make the overlay text look good */

.overlay-title h3,
.overlay-title h5 {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list">
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://preview.ibb.co/eEi2Cb/CBSE_Building_design_plans.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I didn't use pseudo-elements in the above example, I applied the gradient to the overlay division instead, with some additional settings like setting `left` and `bottom` to zero and provided some size to make it look good.

*Consider using the [box-sizing reset](http://w3bits.com/box-sizing-reset/) in your projects to avoid sizing issues.*

Using flexbox was a little tricky here, as I needed the overlay division to have some size (100% of the available space), and then I needed to align the contents to the bottom. This might make you to use an inner division for the alignment sake, which I tried avoiding by making use of **Flexbox columns**.

We should not forget the other background properties here, like `background-repeat`, `background-size`, and `background-position`. They will help you position the gradient perfectly as you might have seen already in the example snippet above.

Hope this was helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can only add pseudo elements to certain elements like spans, li's, anchor tags, p and h elements. Try throwing a span in the containing div and style that to give you a gradient.

The after style also needs a `content: ' ';` to tell the DOM that there is something after.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add an `:after` psuedo-element to an `img` element. But you can add the `background` to an `:after` psuedo-element on the `.category-details` and use `z-index` to position the text over the gradient.

Also, don't forget the browser prefixes.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category-list li {
  flex: 0 1 31%;
  position: relative;
}

.category {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: #00ae6f;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.category-details {
  position: relative;
}

.category-details:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 16px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.overlay-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.overlay-title h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list">
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get exactly what you need by adding `div` or `span` next to image as below. I have added `<div class="bottom-gradient"></div>` next to image.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.category-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.category-list li {
  flex: 0 1 31%;
  position: relative;
}

.category-details img:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  z-index: 999;
}

.category {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: #00ae6f;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.category-details {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.overlay-title h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.bottom-gradient {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 23%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 81%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 92%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-list">
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <div class="bottom-gradient"></div>
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://preview.ibb.co/eEi2Cb/CBSE_Building_design_plans.jpg" />
      <div class="bottom-gradient"></div>
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="category-details">
      <img class="category-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/dWGHdG/kimberlyphoto_medium.jpg" />
      <div class="bottom-gradient"></div>
      <a href="#" class="category">Education</a>
      <div class="overlay-title">
        <h3>Elementary school</h3>
        <h5>297 stephens st. pressville</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```