# Content url change via CSS is not working in Firefox

Tags: css

Css:

```
.woocommerce-placeholder.wp-post-image {
    content: url("DSC0926-1.jpg");
}

/*for firefox*/
.woocommerce-placeholder.wp-post-image::before {
    content: url("DSC0926-1.jpg");
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="placeholder.png" alt="Placeholder" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" scale="0" width="100" height="100">
```

I am trying to replace the placeholder image via CSS. It works in Chrome and Safari, but the `::before` fix that I put for Firefox, doesn't work. Why is that?

P.S. I know similar questions have been posted before but I have tried all those solutions like `:after` and `content: ''; background: url('DSC0926-1.jpg');` instead of changing content url is not working either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS :after not adding content to certain elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because

> The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to replaced elements such as `<img>`, or to `<br>` elements.

as mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

**W3C [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) suggests that**

> **Note:** This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification.