# Firefox not displaying :after pseudo-element

Tags: css

I'm using a pseudo element to display a fallback profile picture when a user does not upload his/her own. The fallback picture works well on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Any idea what causes this?

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

**CSS**

```
.agent-photo{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.agent-photo:before {
  background-image: url('../img/default-user-2.jpg');
  background-size: 70px 70px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
}

.agent-thumbnail-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.confirmation-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="agent-thumbnail-container">
    <img class="agent-photo" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000${agent.profile_pic}" alt="">
    <img class="agent-check" src="img/checkmark-green-circle.svg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers don't support pseudo-elements on img tags.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content):

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements/6949190#6949190) for an explanation as to why.

Comment: we should flag question as duplicate instead of repeating the same answer. If you cannot flag, add it as comment

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation. I ended up using the built-in onerror function to render the fallback picture.