# Make a square img element

Tags: html, css

I'm able to make a square `div` element. But the same styles applied to an `img` tag create a collapsed element- not a square.

```css
.square{
  width:20%; 
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.square:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
img:<br>
<img class='square'/>
<br>
div:<br>
<div class='square'></div>
```

It seems this is because `img` tags are *replaced elements* and `:before` and `:after` only work with *non-replaced elements*. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949148/css-after-not-adding-content-to-certain-elements#answer-6949190)

But I want the `img` element to stay square even if the image source doesn't load. So how can I make a square empty `img`?

Comment: use an extra wrapper (last part here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting `img` in a wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  border:3px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden; /*  helpful if you make border radius 50% turning this into a circle */
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  /* css below helps keep the wrapper square when the image src is tall and skinny */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><img src="blank.gif"/></div>
```