# Double borders in CSS

Tags: html, image, css, border

I'm creating PHP, Javascript based photo-gallery from scratch

The problem is, I want to make difference between simple picture and photo-album.

So simple picture borders look like that

[image]

Is that possible to create facebook like photo-album borders (double borders, which creates multiple images effect) via css or CSS3?

[image]

P.S Don't know if it will be possible with old css standarts. I mean, CSS3 probably can do it but it will not be backward compatible. In other hand, currently my php side generates 100x100 px thumbs. I need something that will not be ruined if I will increase size of thumbs.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL9PX/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="facebook-album"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook-album, .facebook-album:before
{
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #999;
    position: relative;
}
.facebook-album:before
{
    margin: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    background: white;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Use a pseudo element like `:before` or `:after`, for example:</strike>
Turns out, most browsers [don't like :before on images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags) because it's not a text-containing element. You could still do this if you did it on an alternative element, like a div, and set the div's background to the original image. Or, you could try:
http://jsbin.com/otivaj/edit#html,live

Comment: @epic_syntax sure, gimme a minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

You could just look at Facebook's source to figure it out.  This will also work:

http://jsfiddle.net/g9A6a/

Comment: It's not? that looks absolutely perfect.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can definitely do this with CSS. It looks like all your images are the same size, too, which will make this very straightforward. Simply place your `<img>` inside a containing element with `position: relative;` and an offset. Both the container and image should have a border, with padding and offsets you so desire. Set the width and height of the containing element based off the child image's dimensions.

Here is a
[DEMO on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NuR6H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can achieve that effect with simply CSS2. If adding more markup is an option, I would do something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><img></li>
</ul>

li {
    position: relative; 
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
img {
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    left: 6px;
    background-color:white;
}
```