# CSS triangle for image tag

Tags: html, css

I'm searching for a way to add a border triangle (with transparent tips) with an img html tag.
It's work with a div but not with an image tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyH48/2131/

```
.mybox {
    width:200px;   
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.mybox:after, .mybox:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.mybox:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-top-color: red;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.mybox:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: red;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `<img>` tag as `display:block;`. And tell me how it goes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hyH48/2132/ It worked for me, only in Firefox tho.

Comment: Thanks, I need a cross browser solution

Comment: you'll need jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements?lq=1

Comment: ok, try adapting the CSS to other browsers from the solution I gave you. Or pick another solution more Global. (second options is better). Good luck friend! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use pseudo elements with the image tag check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements)

You will have to wrap your image with for example a `div` element and set the pseudo elements on that element.

Comment: I can't wrap the image. The image is a marker on a map, the map API only accept image for markers and no HTML.

Comment: @Ludovic You could try using jQuery to wrap the image in a div tag if you realy can't change the HTML

Comment: Seems to me you need a new image...that's all.

Comment: @Ludovic I think Paulie_D is right, simplest solution would be to implement your triangle directly in your image

Comment: Yes I'm agree I need an image but images are dynamically send to the map (it's user avatar).  I'll ask the designer to change his design :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585070/css-after-pseudo-element-not-showing-up-on-img)

Most browsers do not support using :after or :before on img tags.