# :after in a <img> element unexpected result

Tags: css, image, css-selectors

I have this css:

section#single-result > div > div.horizontal-scroll > div img {
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

and layout is more or less like this:

```
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
     <div>
         <img alt="" src="path.jpg">
             <img alt="" src="path.jpg">
             <img alt="" src="path.jpg">
     </div>
</div>
```

The thing is that i would like to an arrow on top of the first image, so I am trying with the after pseudo element

```
section#single-result > div > div.horizontal-scroll > div img:first-child:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

but this won't even show a red block on top of it,

any idea what am i missing? is that :after with img don't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` `pseudo-elements` Can not be used `IMG Tag`, `input tag`

**[MOre info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element)**

You cannot use `:before` or `:after` on **[img in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags)**