# Blur borders on image via css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: example]

I think it could be done using background image and another image (mask) above it with a transparent center. But is it possible to do the same with pure css?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whilst you can't apply a `box-shadow` directly to an image you could apply it with a `:before or :after`

```css
    .shadow
    {
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .shadow:before
    {
        display:block;
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
        box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    }
```

```html
        <div class="shadow">
                <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg">
        </div>
```

Comment: I assume that the first line is ".shadow" not ".shadow img" yes?
It is not working for me although that it clearly should.  What's wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/FVfgn/

Comment: :before and :after pseudo elements aren't supported on <img> elements, sadly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags

Comment: Updated, I had meant to wrap it in a div :) my bad

Answer (score 5):

Yess it's possible like this:

```
.img {
border:1px solid black;
}
.img:hover {
border: none;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px black inset;
}
```