# Apply overlay gradient to images just like myspace

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply gradient overlay to a lot of images just like [myspace](http://myspace.com) did in their new design . All the images have a title with black gradient background .

I searched but most of the tutorials are shown using a background image on a div . I want to apply this property to all the `<img>` tags appearing on my page.

[Here's](http://alexcarpenter.me/blog/2013/background-image-gradient-overlay) the closest tutorial I found in terms of what I want to achieve . But this is also explained using a background image.

[image]

If you look at the background of the title. The black background ensures that the text is clear enough .

Can you please help me out in writing a general css for achieveing this on all images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really put more effort into trying it out first.. I found this interesting so I got you started..
http://jsfiddle.net/MpmNc/1/

```
.overlay {
    content: 'test';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(100,255,50,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.overlay-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesnt seem like css alone will suffice
[Does :before not work on img elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags)

For your gradient:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thank you @RyanS. I want to apply that bottom black linear-gradient background which makes the title more visible. I want to apply that property to each and every image on my page . I am trying it myself also :)

Comment: Check out the link I added

Comment: thnx man finally got it.

Comment: Care to share? @Mj1992

Comment: yeah used your gradient site to generate the code and copied it in a css class