# How to display img alt text using CSS?

Tags: css

I've tried this and it works fine

```
<p alt="world">hello</p>
```

With CSS

```
p::after {
  content: attr(alt);
}
```

---

But it doesn't work when I try

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="my image caption">
```

With CSS

```
img::after {
  content: attr(alt);
}
```

---

**Is it possible to output alt text for an `img` using CSS?**

Please indicate browser compatibility with any solution you provide.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fs76v/)

Comment: not using CSS alone, you can using JS or jQuery.

Comment: `alt` attribute is only valid HTML on `img`, `input[type="image"]` and `area` elements (and object[type="image"] but that's anecdotal). It's also mandatory (and can have an empty value like `alt=""` in some contexts)

Answer (score 13):

**This is by design.**

`img` tags are self-closing (`<tag />`) tag, and therefore they contain no "content". Since they do not contain any content, no `content` can be appended (i.e. `::after`) or prepended (i.e. `::before`).

This is also the case for other self-closing HTML elements:

> `<area>`, `<base>`, `<br>`, `<col>`, `<command>`, `<embed>`, `<hr>`, `<keygen>`,
>   `<link>`, `<meta>`, `<param>`, `<source>`, `<track>` and `<wbr>`

Here's what the (CSS2) Spec says:

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification. **[2014: hasn't happened yet]**

**Source:** http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

Comment: Yup. `:after` is actually `:end-of-innerHTML`. `:before` is actually `:start-of-innerHTML`. And self-closing tags don't have innerHTML.

Comment: How disappointing. There's no way around this then?

Comment: @naomik Beg the spec writers to make the spec suck less. Then expect IE support in 2100.

Comment: there is another question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-tags