# how to use font flaction icon for img and asp:ImageButton

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i want use font awesome in my form.

my form content img and asp:imagebutton.

i want use font awesome in img tag but this not work.

my code is :

```
    <img id="imgsaleNew" title="Create" runat="server" class="flaticon-yield" onclick="imgsaleNew_OnClick();" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgsaleOpen" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Open"                                            OnClick="imgsaleOpen_Click" class="flaticon-yield"/>
```

My Css Class Is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("Font/flaticon.eot");
    src: url("Font/flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("Font/flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("Font/flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("Font/flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
    font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 63px;
    font-style: normal;
    color:#368ee0;
}.flaticon-yield:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23brK/1/) ..

in your **CSS**

```
.flaticon-yield:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

it looks that you're using `content:"\e000"` which does not exist in **FontAwesome** ..

Try another `content`, and you can get that from this [page](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

Also, Unfortunately, most browsers do not support using :after or :before on img tags.

Take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements) for more info

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: thanks.but my code worked in a,i,div tag but not work for img and asp:imagebutton tag.
do can use font icon for img and asp:imageButton tag?

Comment: in the demo. you can see that font works in `asp:ImageButton` but not `img` ... if you want an icon showing in place of the `img`, That's only possible if you use the parent element and hide the `img` inside of it. That's because img elements can't have **pseudo elements**, which is used to display the icons. You could wrap the img in a figure tag and apply the icon class to that

Comment: @HapyUser see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/23brK/4/ , is it what you're looking for ??