# why does the :before pseudo tag not add color overlay to this figure

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

need this color overlay to cover this image but it does not.  Is this even possible with a figure/figcaption? I dont really understand why this isnt working I have it set like this several other places on my website for class.
thanks.
HTML

```
<figure>
<img src="img/cala.jpg">
<figcaption>About This</figcaption>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
figure {
}
figure img {
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}
figure > img:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(11, 52, 150, 0.5);
    z-index: 9001;
}
figcaption {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `:before` on an image element. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements

Comment: Wrap the `img` in a `div`, and do it to the `div`.

Comment: thanks for the info and link share

Comment: yup Alexander thats where I was headed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:before` pseudo element does no work on `img` elements

[Here is what the spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)...

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of `:before` and `:after` with replaced elements **(such as IMG in HTML)**. This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

Answer (score 1):

most browsers don't support `:before` and `:after` elements on img. try it on the figcaption instead.

```
figure figcaption:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(11, 52, 150, 0.5);
}
```