# CSS add marker/symbol over an element

Tags: html, css

I have two images:

```
<img ng-src="image1.jpg" class="regular">
<img ng-src="image2.jpg" class="favorite">
```

For the second image, I am looking for a way to structure my CSS class such that a marker/symbol appears over the image (example a star for favorite or just a letter - maybe a drawing). Is there a way to do so?

Comment: there are lots of ways, what html/css do you have so far?

Comment: z-index Property will work for you? Stili some code would help

Comment: The name of the effect you are lookig for is called "overlay". Now just google , you will have a much better idea. Unless you want us to do your work

Answer (score 3):

As `<img>` element cannot have pseudo content, so you could wrap it into a `<span>` tag or so into the markup, and apply the pseudo content on it instead.

```css
.favorite {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.favorite:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="favorite"><img src="//dummyimage.com/100x100"/></span>
```

Comment: I had something quite similar, using font-awesome. Render could be better : http://fiddle.jshell.net/msieurtoph/ndgha1g9/ (Dont miss the link to the font-awesome styles sheet)

Comment: @M'sieurToph' nice! as it's just for the demo purpose so trying to make things as simple as possible.

Comment: ...and you were right ;) I did not want to post another similar answer, so I put my link as a comment of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute position works.

Try:

With:

```
.regular {
 position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

.favorite {
 position: absolute;
 left: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zyng2Lxj/

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking for. He's not trying to overlay one on the other..he's trying to add an overlay a third image on the "favourite" image.

Answer (score 1):

as image tag doesn't support after pseudoelement, what about a little jquery code like:

```
$(function() {

    $('.favorite').after('<img src="" class="icon" />');

});
```

the position the image with the class as in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ahnGT/177/)**

(all credit to @Christopher Harris for his answer at [Does :before not work on img elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements))