# CSS adjust style of element where its child does have class

Tags: wordpress, css, pseudo-element, buddypress, pseudo-class

Is there a pure CSS way to adjust styling of an element where its only child does not have a class?

For example:

```
<a><img class="avatar pro"></a>
<a><img class="avatar"></a>
```

And I only want to style "a" containing a child with the class "pro"?

Background is the following:
In Buddypress, you have a hook to add a class for avatars:

```
add_filter( 'bp_core_avatar_class', 'filter_bp_core_avatar_class', 10, 4 );
```

However, since :before / :after-pseudo-classes do not work on images, I need to be able to adjust the wrapping container.

Thanks!
Raphael

Answer (score 3):

No, there currently are no parent selectors purely in CSS. Here's a discussion on it: https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

However, if you're using Buddypress, jQuery comes autorolled with it. You could add a script to a theme file like the following:

```
$( "img.pro" ).parent().css( "border", "5px solid red" );
```

Comment: Thanks. Solution with JS is obvious, but I really don't like to use JS for styling purposes. But I also see no way to add a class to the wrapping container in Buddypress, so...

Comment: You might want to ask that over at the WordPress StackExchange community - they might be able to help you over there find a way to add a class to the wrapping container.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185336/add-class-to-link-surrounding-avatar

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a discussion about `:before` and `:after` for elements that *do not contain text*.

However, there is a pure CSS way. In this discussion here

[Does :before not work on img elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements)

TimPietrusky demonstrates it (scroll down). The solution is here at the CodePen:

http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/xpesA

The clever guy uses the `content` attribute to set text, and once there is text, `:after` and `:before` will/should/could apply. Then he designs `:before` and `:after` to match his expectations. I like it, but it is a classical "misuse" of side effects that has to be managed on many browsers.

Comment: So much for "pure CSS" in that Situation :-)

Answer (score -1):

My first go would be styling the `<a class='something'>` instead of the img.

Comment: I would not have asked this question if it were that easy, right? ;) Please read again: Buddypress as a framework has a hook for the avatar img, but I think there's no hook for the wrapping tag so no chance to add a class there!