# CSS Pseudo Elements do not work with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, pseudo-element

I am listing some images with ng-repeat, and want to apply a pseudo class with some content after it.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Noitidart/y7dxa6n8/11/

And here is the code:

```
<style>
    body {background-color:steelblue;}
    img::after { content: 'rawr'; size:100px; color:red; }
</style>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <img ng-repeat="aSrc in mc.arr" ng-src="{{aSrc}}"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('MyController', [function($cookie) {
           this.arr = ['https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png']
}]);
```

However the pseudo class wont work. This is very odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its not about a matter of angular `ng-repeat`

just check `<img />` without angular and check with the `::before`

like

```
<img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">

img::after { content: 'rawr'; size:100px; color:red; }
```

its not working because of most of the browsers not support `::before`, `::after` on `img` elements

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements)

Comment: Wowwwww I struggled with this piece of crap for an hour and half and then took a dinner break. Thanks man you saved me such a headache!!

Comment: ah :) glad to hear that cheerz :)