# Hover image not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the image to fade to black and to display a + sign in the center on hover but it isn't working.

```
.block-img img {
width:710px;
margin-bottom:50px;
position:relative;
}

.block-img img:hover:after {
opacity: 1;
}

.block-img img:after {
box-sizing: border-box;
content:"+";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: black;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-out;
transition: opacity 100ms ease-out;
color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbd4chkd/

Comment: just `.block-img img:hover {`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pbd4chkd/2/  <-- the hover action works here... your css needs some tweaking though

Comment: Unfortunately, most browsers do not support using `:after` or `:before` on `img` tags. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements).