# Looking for a way to override an image using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm seeking a way to override the src of an image. The html setting the image is:

```
<img src="/img/commerce/reports/view_manager.gif" alt="View Manager" title="View Manager" border="0">
```

The location of the image is hardcoded and cannot be modified in this site as the code is proprietary. I am able to override the image using the following css:

```
.commerce-sidebar-item[href*='displayViewManager'] > img {
    content: url("https://cpq-p10-022.bigmachines.com/bmfsweb/cpq-p10-022/image/apps_20.png")!important;
}
```

But it does not work in Firefox. I then found that using :before or :after may resolve the issue. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/897824

Alas, that doesn't work in this site.

Are there any other alternatives to override the image source using css or javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag ?

Comment: You can run JS on the page? If so, how "location ... cannot be modified"?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag ..

Comment: Pseudo elements don't work on img tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements  You're going to need JS; CSS won't accomplish this task.

Comment: If you're really set on CSS but your HTML is flexible, you could use a background-image instead. That would be easy to switch out using CSS. That requires you to set the dimensions of the "containing" div beforehand, so you can `contain` the background image or have it `cover` the container, using the `background-size` property. But since you listed this under JavaScript as well: Changing the `src` attribute would be the go-to move

Comment: Thank you for the responses. 
Modifying the html is not an option as the site is proprietary and has locked down the html. 

I am able to use background-image: url() to render the desired image. However, it now shows behind the image I want to hide. 
Can anyone think of a way to hide the original image source, linked to the img element and at the same time display the background-image?

Comment: What do you mean with "has locked down the HTML"? If you can execute JS on a page, you can do what ever you want to its HTML, like `document.querySelector('.commerce-sidebar-item[href*='displayViewManager'] > img').src = ' ... ';`