# is there possible to use before and after for inline elements?

Tags: html, css, inline

I have tried to get after pseudo for image but nothing appears ,Is this a wrong way or we can't have :after :beforfe for inline elements.

```css
img:after{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:red;
right:-100%;
}

img{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSkokrxxIX-EDiBFHl7z-gDrIscZSa2KDgl5Xm1-31053Zb1yvb"/>
```

Comment: what is that you want to do can you explain more and add code fiddle also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements - has your answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is wrong way to use `::after` & `::before` you can add a parent div of img than you can use `::before` and `::after`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few basics you need to know like, use of `content:''` and `figure`.

```css
figure:after{
    content:''; /*if you are using :after or :before you have to use content*/
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    right:-100%;
}

figure{
    position:relative;
    width: 400px; /*just for test*/
}
```

```html
<figure> <!-- HTML5 :) -->
    <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSkokrxxIX-EDiBFHl7z-gDrIscZSa2KDgl5Xm1-31053Zb1yvb"
     >
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I respect all answers but it doesn't work with `img` tag, you have to use a parent to make it work with `img` tag. Although it works with other inline tage like `a`,`span` etc. Hope it will help you.

One thing please do add `content:"";` whenever you do css for `before` and `after`
Thanks